# Building controller using Spring RestController and Jackson give me HTTP Stats 406

Tags: java, json, http, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm building a rest controller using Spring to handle request and Jackson to serialize data.However I followed tutorial online but I end up getting an error.

```
HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

After Google for a while, I realized that it is because I don't have "application/json" as my "Accept" header in my request:
[image]

So I use a tool called Postman to manually add this "Accept" header in the request, send the request again, but still getting the same error:

[image]

I'm so confused, I've already included "application/json" as one of accepted data-type, why I still have this data-unsupported error? FYI, here is my Rest Controller class:

```
package mywebapp.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import mywebapp.dao.model.interfaces.PetDao;
import mywebapp.model.Pet;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "petJson.htm")
public class PetControllerAjax {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PetController.class);


    public static Logger getLog() {
        return LOG;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("PetDaoJpaImpl")
    private PetDao petDao;

    public PetDao getPetDao() {
        return petDao;
    }

    public void setPetDao(PetDao petDao) {
        this.petDao = petDao;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Pet> getAllPets() throws IOException {
        getLog().info("Rest Controller activating........");
        List<Pet> petList = getPetDao().getAllPets();
        return petList;
    }

}
```

And here is my Pet entity class:

```
package mywebapp.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pet")
public class Pet {

    private int petId;

    private String name;

    private String owner;

    private String species;

    private String sex;

    private Date birth;

    private Date death;

    private Set<Toy> toys;  


    @Id
    @Column(name = "pet_id")
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonProperty(value="pet_id",required=true)
    public int getId() {
        return petId;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.petId = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="pet_name",required=true)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getSpecies() {
        return species;
    }

    public void setSpecies(String species) {
        this.species = species;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Date getBirth() {
        return birth;
    }

    public void setBirth(Date birth) {
        this.birth = birth;
    }

    public Date getDeath() {
        return death;
    }

    public void setDeath(Date death) {
        this.death = death;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity=Toy.class, mappedBy="pet")
    public Set<Toy> getToys() {
        return toys;
    }

    public void setToys(Set<Toy> toys) {
        this.toys = toys;
    }



}
```

Anyone knows what's going on here? Any hint will be appreciated, lots of thanks in advance!

Comment: Which Spring and Jackson versions are you using? What happens if you add a `produces` attribute in your `@RequestMapping` annotation to force the `"application/json"` media type?

Comment: @BrianClozel Hi, I'm using 4.2.5.RELEASE for Spring and 2.7.0-rc2 for Jackson

Answer (score 0):

Jackson 2.7 is not supported by Spring 4.2 - it will be in 4.3+.

Check out the library requirements for Spring on [the Spring wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework) and see [SPR-13728](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13728) and [SPR-13483](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13483).